# Jasny bootstrap offcanvas menu does not dismiss on mobile (iPhone 6 Chrome)

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, jasny-bootstrap

I am using the offcanvas plugin from Jasny Bootstrap to implement a menu. It works as expected on a desktop browser. However, on mobile (iPhone 6 to be exact) the menu does not dismiss if the user clicks outside the menu. On a desktop browser, when an offcanvas menu is displayed, clicking outside the menu area dismisses the menu. Am I missing something, is this a bug, or is this expected behavior?

I reproduced this problem comparing desktop Chrome and iPhone Chrome using the supplied Jasny Bootstrap menu sample:

http://www.jasny.net/bootstrap/examples/navmenu-push/

Comment: I have posted a similar question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35682102/jasny-bootstrap-mobile-view)

Answer (score 1):

tyipss!
Perhaps, it's a bug, though it looks like I can reproduce it only on a real iPhone6 (not in Chrome dev tools).
You can hide the menu explicitly in its callback function, like here:

```
$('.your-menu-selector').on('shown.bs.offcanvas', function() {
  $('.your-backdrop-element').on('click', function() {
    $('.your-menu-selector').offcanvas('hide');
  });
});
```